# Make a Label Copyable

Tags: ios, web-applications, copy, label, clipboard

I'm developing a WebApp for iOS which has a `Label` that will show a result for the user that should be copied for further use, but how I can make the `Label` content copyable?

Answer (score 0):

u could add a copy button near the label, when the user tapps it, the value of the label is stored in a var and could be inserted at another point of the application...

or, if u want the labeltext in the clipboard, u could use this:
http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-3-copy-paste-with-uipasteboard/

u can get the text from the label via mylabeloutlet.text and store it in the pastboard, so the user can insert it into another textfield/inputfield